# Outlook VBA code to search inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write an Outlook macro that will cycle through my inbox and search each email Subject line for text containing a six digit integer (job number) e.g. `102296` and then move any emails with that job number in the subject line to a sub folder named by the job number. There could be any number of job folders, all named starting with a unique 6 digit job number, followed by a job title e.g. `102296-energy` report. I've written code that searches the emails for a manually imputed job number, but want to automate the process further.

Comment: A good start (to avoid your question getting closed) would be to show your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all items in the folder is a time-consuming task which can take a lot of time. I'd suggest using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210275(v=office.11).aspx) methods to get items that correspond to your condition.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Im getting there with my code, but want to use regex to find actual 6 digit numbers only, my code so far is below:-